# Translation of the Latin lyrics in Avenged Sevenfold's "Requiem"?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, song-lyrics

In [Avenged Sevenfold's "Requiem"](https://youtu.be/mV7bND-_KdI) there is a passage in Latin at the very beginning of the song. It says something like:

> Prodigia comploratus
>   Silens, oro
>   Regnet exitium

I know nothing about this language but I assume that the written text above is Latin. What does that mean (if it means anything at all)?

You have got to realize that it's a song too. Grammar doesn't have much meaning in songs, at least in English.

Comment: There was a suggested edit: "Didn’t see a reply button so I’m just doing this, sorry about that, but the meaning behind it is “ Prodigies bewailed, please reign destruction” and the rest of the song talks about the destruction of earth and the darkest lord." (There is a text box below all the other answers where you can write a new one. If you do so, please see the other answers and explain how you ended up with your answer. I declined the suggested edit as it was an answer, not an improvement on the question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alas, @Tendero, I'm afraid that *prodigia comploratus silens oro regnet exitium* doesn't have a coherent meaning as a Latin expression.

*Comploratus silens* means something like "silent lamentation," but there isn't any way for *prodigia* (which means "wonders" or "miracles") to go along with it grammatically—"silent lamentation of wonders" would work in English but for the Latin to mean that, *prodigia* would have to be something like *prodigiis*. *Oro **ut** regnet exitium* would mean more or less "I beg destruction to reign" or "I beg that destruction might reign," but without the *ut*, as in the lines you quote, it doesn't really work either.

I hope this isn't too disappointing!

Comment: It looks like someone fed an English sentence into an automated "translator" and the machine spewed out this gibberish. Maybe someone might feel like repeating the exercise in the opposite direction.

Comment: Well, http://translate.google.com gives me, "Prodigies bewailed Silent, please reign destruction."

Comment: The "English" and the "Latin" seem to be of similar quality.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, I disagree: this sentence does have a coherent meaning in Latin, if my parsing is correct.

Rather than as a noun, I read *comploratus* as the past participle of [*comploro*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcomploro) which has attested forms of taking the accusative (see the first example in the linked entry). It is rare and post-Augustinian, but it is not *incorrect*.

The rest is not hard to put together, if you understand *comploratus* as a past participle and *silens* as a present participle both modifying *ego*. The last trick would be to put a colon after *oro* and see "regnet exitium" as direct discourse:

```
Prodigia comploratus,       Having bewailed these [bad] portents,
silens, oro:                Keeping silence, I pray:
"Regnet exitium."           "Let destruction reign."
```

### Edit:

As @TKR pointed out in the comments, *comploratus* can only be interpreted as active ("having bewailed") rather than passive ("having been bewailed") if it is deponent. I do not see any precedent for this, so it turns out that the phrase *is*  bad Latin, because a passive participle cannot take an accusative direct object in this way.

I *still* think that this is a more probable interpretation of what they were getting at and shows perhaps a little more effort on their part than visiting our friends at [Google Translate](http://google.com/translate).

### Edit 2

Per Cerberus's comment, there is another grammatical interpretation, though its meaning is less clear. Since *sileo* (like *taceo*) can take an accusative object to mean, "to keep X silent", we could interpret *complaratūs* (4th declension) as genitive and *prodigia* as the object of *silens.* We thus get:

> Keeping silence over these portents of grief, I pray: "Let destruction reign."